# BinaryString Comparison Java Beginner

Tags: java

I have the current code:

```
public class Individual{

    static int DNA_LOWER_DOMAIN = -100;
    static int DNA_UPPER_DOMAIN = 100;


    private double fitness = 0.0;
    private int x_coordinate = 0;
    private String bit_x_coordinate;

    Individual(){
        int number = DNA_LOWER_DOMAIN + (int)(Math.random() * (DNA_UPPER_DOMAIN - DNA_LOWER_DOMAIN) + 1);
        x_coordinate = number;

        bit_x_coordinate = Integer.toBinaryString(x_coordinate);
    }

    public void store_gene(int i, int get_gene) {

        bit_x_coordinate = bit_x_coordinate.replace(bit_x_coordinate.charAt(i),(char) get_gene);

    }
}
```

The function that calls store_gene

```
private static Individual crossover(Individual inhabitant1, Individual inhabitant2){

    Individual child = new Individual();

    for(int i = 0; i < inhabitant1.size(); i++){

        if(Math.random() <= uniformalRate){

            child.store_gene(i, inhabitant1.get_gene(i));

        }
        else{

            child.store_gene(i, inhabitant2.get_gene(i));
        }


    }

    return child;
}
```

anyway when I go to compare using the index of the binary string, I have an out of bounds error because negative integers will be longer than positive ones, any idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Where is the comparison code?

Comment: @gotuskar Ive added that its a function that stores a given int to another string but its a part of an algorithm

Comment: You will have a random number between 0 and 201.  The binary version of that will be from 1 to 8 digits long.  I don't see any code calling `store_gene` but if it is called with a first parameter longer than the number of digits you will get an error.  Please include code calling `store_gene`.

Comment: Done, Ive included it now:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive solved the problem like this

Individual(){
        int number = DNA_LOWER_DOMAIN + (int)(Math.random() * (DNA_UPPER_DOMAIN - DNA_LOWER_DOMAIN) + 1);
        x_coordinate = number;

```
    bit_x_coordinate = Integer.toBinaryString(x_coordinate);
    if(bit_x_coordinate.length() < 32){

    int number_of_bits = bit_x_coordinate.length();

        for(int i = 0; i < (32-number_of_bits); i++){

        bit_x_coordinate = "0" + bit_x_coordinate;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for letting us know how you solved. Please remember to [mark the answer that solved your problem as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

ToBinaryString() doesn't print the leading zeros. You have to pad the String.

Comment: If str.length < 32 then insert 0s at the beginning. Eg with a stringbuilder

Comment: Could You give me more straight comment? I am a beginner at Java, thanks :)